# Getting timestamps in deterministic way in Hyperledger Composer transactions

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

Is there a deterministic way to get timestamp in  transaction function, similar to stub.GetTxTimestamp() that can be used in Go version of Fabric's chaincode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just sharing an example that works with `basic-sample-network` network:

In the model file (`lib/org.acme.sample.cto`) I extended `SampleAsset` definition any added new property called `timestamp` of type `DateTime`:

```
asset SampleAsset identified by assetId {
  o String assetId
  --> SampleParticipant owner
  o String value
  o DateTime timestamp
}
```

In the script file (`lib/logic.js`), the `onSampleTransaction` function to update SampleAsset's `timestamp` with current transaction's timestamp:

```
function onSampleTransaction(sampleTransaction) {
  sampleTransaction.asset.value = sampleTransaction.newValue;
  sampleTransaction.asset.timestamp = sampleTransaction.timestamp;
  return getAssetRegistry('org.acme.sample.SampleAsset')
       .then(function (assetRegistry) {
               return assetRegistry.update(sampleTransaction.asset);
        });
}
```

Comment: But it's possible that some malevolent or malfunctioning node could stamp a wrong timestamp?

Answer (score 1):

All transactions have a system property called `timestamp`, so you can use `myTransaction.timestamp`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for response, Dan! Here is the sample that works for basic-sample-network (assuming that asset "SampleAsset" has the property called "timestamp" that we want to update with the following transaction "SampleTransaction"): `function onSampleTransaction(sampleTransaction) {
    sampleTransaction.asset.value = sampleTransaction.newValue;
   sampleTransaction.asset.timestamp = sampleTransaction.timestamp;
    return getAssetRegistry('org.acme.sample.SampleAsset')
      .then(function (assetRegistry) {
          return assetRegistry.update(sampleTransaction.asset);
      });
}`

Comment: https://github.com/hyperledger-archives/fabric/issues/1832 we cannot use the proto from the vendor folder ...

Answer (score 0):

we cannot use the proto from the vendor folder ...

https://github.com/hyperledger-archives/fabric/issues/1832