# Hyperledger Composer timestamp

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have the same doubt as this question

[Getting timestamps in deterministic way in Hyperledger Composer transactions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43656164/getting-timestamps-in-deterministic-way-in-hyperledger-composer-transactions)

My Question is will it not lead to non deterministic code.
For instance if I have more than one peer, Wouldn't the timetamp method return different values?

Comment: not if you're usng the inherited system transaction timestamp (as shown in the transaction class in that link) that's the same when sent as a proposal to all peers.

Comment: thanks @PaulO'Mahony